# how can i do this in wp7?

Tags: wcf, image, windows-phone-7, camera, odata

Any ideas on how i can create this app?

1) i have a page which contains 3 tasks and thus has a textbox, a label to contain an image name and another label which is to display my current location..the first is to enter some text into a textbox, the second is to take a picture and come back to this page and display the picture url and the 3rd is to determine and display my location.

2) i need to gather each of these 3 bits of information and upload it to a remote database via WCF or Odata.

3) I know that for example, to either take a picture with my camera or browse to a pix in the pictures hub will take me away from my task page.

how can i take the picture and carry the information back to my task page without losing state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you take a picture, your application will be tombstoned. See the following article for details of how this process works and what you need to do:

http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/07/20/understanding-the-windows-phone-application-execution-model-tombstoning-launcher-and-more-part-3.aspx

Answer (score 2):

To get a picture from the camera you need to use a [CameraCaptureTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769543%28v=vs.92%29.aspx#BKMK_Camera).
To choose an existing picture from the phone you shoudl use a [PhotoChooserTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769543%28v=vs.92%29.aspx#BKMK_Photo).

To get the devices currentl location use the [GeoCoordinateWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431782%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

There should be no issues with loosing state while you capture this information but isf there is you can just store it in the [Page State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967548%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) object.

Note. All links are "How To" articles.